Webparts Permission for SharePoint Online
I have created sites and subsite for a intranet using sharepoint online and would like some of the users to only update properties of the webpart or the content it holds and not delete or add. How can I achieve it?
I have created a custom permission where I only selected Allow them to update or add personal webparts but this does not work.
these are the permissions levels assigned to that custom permission
 
List Permissions

    View Items  -  View items in lists and documents in document libraries.

 
Site Permissions

    View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site.

    Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container.


 
Personal Permissions

    Add/Remove Personal Web Parts  -  Add or remove personal Web Parts on a Web Part Page.

    Update Personal Web Parts  -  Update Web Parts to display personalized information.

I thought this would allow users to only update webparts they have added and could not delete webparts already added by other users but not working. is it possible to do it?
also, after doing some research I even added these permission from List Permissions but then users were able to not only delete their own but could also delete others webparts.
    Add Items  -  Add items to lists and add documents to document libraries.
View Application Pages  -  View forms, views, and application pages. Enumerate lists.


create a permission add, but not modify or delete https://mytenant/sites/aSite/_layouts/15/role.aspx

can you please explain in detail, i do not get your point. As I specifically do not want users to add but to modify.

As far as I know, there is no such permission setting to prevent user delete the webpart with edit permission. As a workaround, I would recommend you to use SharePoint Event Receiver.
Once the user deleting the webpart, you could use custom code to stop theuser

You have to navigate to your site collection permissions
Create a new permission level
Affect your permission to à SharePoint group
Or affect the permission in your document library permissions settings





Hi Frederic, I have tried it but its not working users are able to delete other users webparts.
